# Returning a pointer to a struct pointing to a string

Tags: c

Is this the correct way to create a string in this case.

```
Foo* create()
{
  Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
  foo->name = strdup("Foo");
  return foo;
}
```

I will later have to delete both foo and foo->name myself.

Comment: Would you post all the relevant code?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus what are you missing?

Comment: Is there more to struct foo than the name field? Just curious.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Not in this hypothetical case.

Comment: `Foo *foo = (myStruct *) malloc(sizeof(Foo));` looks like trouble waiting to happen - you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()`, but casting it to the wrong thing is certainly not a good idea... Aside from that, since we don't know what a `Foo` or a `myStruct` look like, there's not much else to be said...

Comment: @twalberg That was a typo which is now fixed. I'm not used to C's malloc as I program normally in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The object allocation isn't entirely correct (you should cast to `Foo*` and not to `mystruct`).</strike> The string allocation is correct, but maybe not exactly what you want.

The `strdup()` function actually calls `malloc()` for you, and you only need this construction if you want to modify the string at a later time (and don't increase its length!!!). You should not forget to call `free()` on the string when you're disposing the `Foo` object.

If `foo->name` is for read-only purposes, declare `foo->name` as a `const char *` and just write `foo->name = "Foo";` to initialize it.

EDIT:
Also note that `strdup()` might return `NULL`, and you should check for it! If it is I would than just `assert()` on it, because out-of-memory errors are pretty unrecoverable. Don't try to handle such kind of errors. This also counts for allocating the `Foo` object too.

Comment: No, I will need to change foo->name. So I should call free() in my name setter also.

Comment: @Baz If you do `foo->name = "anotherone"` or even `foo->name = new_name`, you don't need the `strdup()` thing. If you want to have a copy of `new_name` because it will change later and `foo->name` should not then using `strdup()` is a valid way and indeed you must `free()` the old value before assigning a new one.

Comment: @Baz By "modify the string" I don't mean `foo->name = somevalue`, but actually changing the contents of the string `foo->name` is pointing to (like `foo->name[0] = 'a'` or `strcpy(foo->name, "123")`.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, but you don't have to cast the return pointer of `malloc` (and you shouldn't).